# ApplicationRef and DetectionChange not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-changedetection, applicationreference

I have a button to change the language in my application. The language changes and the page refreshes when the button is pressed, but I want to do this process without refreshing the page.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you think `ApplicationRef` doesn't work?

Comment: what are you using to "change the language" ? which framework/module are you working with? or do you have a custom solution? and if so, how does it work? some more details and code will be needed in order to help here